# Text outside div in Safari only

Tags: html, css, safari

I have this bug that let some text appear a few pixels outside a div on the right side. The strange thing is that it only happens in Safari. I've never seen it before and it's just regular HTML/CSS what I have used. I've looked around on the internet but I can't find the exact same problem - only some problems with content floating out at the bottom, because of a fixed height.

In the next 2 screenshots you'll see the same page in Safari and Chrome. The div has a overlow:hidden to hide a possible third line of text. I added fixed widths when trying to solve the problem. I also tried to add/remove some margins, but I can't get rid of the extra pixels.

[image] [image]

[Here](http://www.snizoo.nl/rijschool/) is a full link to this page. It happens in this section of the website only. In other sections - like [this one](http://www.snizoo.nl/tattoo-shops/) - where I use the same format with little differences, but the same CSS idea (fixed width with overflow:hidden), there is no bug in Safari.

I hope you have some ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `position:absolute` from

`div#branch-search-results-block div.search-result-right div.search-result-drvl-info-bottom .spacer::after`

css style solves the issue. But I am not sure what else is affected by it. Please try this.

Comment: You're awesome! Wouldn't think that could solve it, because the `::after` element is placed within the margin space of it's parent.

I gave the `.spacer` element a minimal width and added `display:block` instead of removing `position:absolute` from the `::after` element (worked out better from cross browser point of view)