# Text wrongly displayed beyond the containing div/paragraph right boundary only on Safari

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, safari, mobile-safari

We are experiencing a strange behaviour on **Safari**, both on **Mac** and **iPhone**.

The issue was detected on **iPhone 7** and **iPhone 8**. Moreover, it was reproduced also on **macOS Sierra**, by relying on the responsive design mode.

As you can see in the following snippet, we have a pretty classical Boostrap-3 row/col hierarchy. Take into account that the parent element of the enclosing *div* in the snippet is the *body* element.

```html
<div class="container-wrapper" id="content-wrapper" style="padding: 80px 0px 0px;">
  <!-- OTHER STUFF -->
  <div class="whats-on-hotel">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="section-name section-name-space text-center">what's on at the hotel</h2>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="/.imaging/bhr-wide-small-jpg/dam/SHANGHAI/what-s-on/what-s-on-opening-shanghai.jpg/jcr%3Acontent" title="La Terrazza of The Bvlgari Hotel Shanghai" alt="La Terrazza of The Bvlgari Hotel Shanghai">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <h3 class="article-title article-title-space first-space">The Bvlgari Hotel Shanghai, the new contemporary glamourous address in China’s most fashionable city, opened its doors</h3>
          <div class="text-copy-01 text-copy-space">
            <p>The Bvlgari Hotel Shanghai has taken its place in the Bvlgari Hotels &amp; Resorts collection.</p>

            <p>On 19th June, the new Bvlgari Hotel Shanghai hosted the launch of Bvlgari Film Week, part of the Shanghai International Film Festival, thereby making its debut as the sixth jewel in the Bvlgari Hotels universe. Bridging the golden age of Shanghai
              with its ...</p>
          </div>
          <a class="link-button btn btn-default" href="http://www.bulgarihotels.com/en_US/london/whats-on/article/London/At-The-Hotel/The-Bvlgari-Hotel-Shanghai,-the-new-contemporary-glamourous-address-in-China’s-most-fashionable-city,-opened-its-doors">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- OTHER STUFF -->

</div>
```

On **Chrome**, **Firefox** and **Android** devices the code is displayed with **no issues**, as you can see from the following screenshot:
[image: Chrome - no issues]

---

Instead, on **Safari**, both on **Mac** and **iOS**, the **rendering issue** appears: as you can see in the screenshot, the text flows beyond the right border of the screen:

[image: Safari - overflowing text]

As you can see from the following screenshots, the *div.col*, *div.text-copy-01* and *p* boundaries are correctly computed. The computed size on Safari is exactly the same as on Chrome and Firefox. Although this, the text "overflows" only on Safari.

1. Highlighted *div.col*:

[image]

2. Highlighted *div.text-copy-01*:

[image]

3. Highlighted *p*:

[image]

---

However, if we **select the text** (obviously it can be done on **Safari for Mac** only), the text gets rearranged correctly, although some characters remain still displayed beyond the boundary of the *div.text-copy-01* and *p*:
[image]

We already tried to play both with percentage and **fixed width**, with **no success**: the text keeps on being displayed beyond the right boundary of its containing elements.

It seems to be a Safari-specific issue. Another user had a similar problem ([Text outside div in Safari only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23779113/text-outside-div-in-safari-only)) but **the suggested solution is not applicable to our case**.

Is it an alredy known issue? Is there any way to circumvent it?

Comment: Just have a question, why if you have col-sm-6 it takes all the width as it was col-sm-12, I think you should change it for 12 since you are using only the 50% of your row i guess.

Comment: Because I am dealing with (and emulating) a iPhone, which is an xs device. If devices are >= sm, those cols are actually displayed one next to each other.

Comment: In that case, don't you should use col-xs-12?

Comment: No need to use it. If you inspect a "col-" div and look at the computed styles, you see that all the "col-" classes always have their padding, min-height and positions set, without any media query restriction. The col-xs-12 would only prescribe "width:100%" on xs devices. However, since a "display:block" div is already as wide as its container, and since col-sm-6 (i.e. "width:50%") applies only to sm devices and above (greater than xs), the col-sm-6 div is already as wide as its container on xs devices. Therefore, the additional col-xs-12 class is redundant (and it's commonly omitted)

Comment: However, I tried anyway to add it, as a last desperate resort, and it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to find a **workaround**. By playing with the inspector, we realized that *the browser correctly redisplayed the text everytime the size or the content of the affected div changed*, in addition to the already mentioned text selection. Unfortunately, it is quite dirty, but it looks like the only working option, by now.

We added a **.redrawn** class to the div's containing the wrongly displayed text. For example:

```html
<div class="text-copy-01 text-copy-space redrawn">
  <p>The Bvlgari Hotel Shanghai has taken its place in the Bvlgari Hotels &amp; Resorts collection.</p>
  <p>On 19th June, the new Bvlgari Hotel Shanghai hosted the launch of Bvlgari Film Week, part of the Shanghai International Film Festival, thereby making its debut as the sixth jewel in the Bvlgari Hotels universe. Bridging the golden age of Shanghai with
    its ...</p>
</div>
```

Then, we **clear** and **re-add** the contained **HTML**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".redrawn").each(function(index, elementToRedraw) {
    var $elementToRedraw = $(elementToRedraw);
    var html = $elementToRedraw.html();
    $elementToRedraw.html("");
    $elementToRedraw.html(html);
  });
});
```

By this, we can apply the workaround to every piece of text that may be affected by the bug. In order to reduce the impact, we will also limit the execution of this piece of JS to Safari only. We see that there are plenty of ways to detect a browser, either by User Agent or feature detection. However, this is out of the scope of the question.